# asp.net core app deploy as portable dll's (target full .net461)

Tags: asp.net, .net

In the context of asp.net core 1.0 apps there is the notion of portability. Either you pick to publish a portable app (dll's) and guarantee the installation of windows server hosting bundle on the server yourself and setup the site in IIS *or* you pick to publish a self contained app which doesn't need anything installed on the server and should not be setup in IIS.

Separately to this, there is a way of specifying the .net461 framework in project.json like so:

```
"frameworks": {
   ".net461": {}
  },
```

When the project.json file contains that code, it automatically generates, what looks to be, a self contained app, which is an exe and a bunch of dependent dll's. Classic asp.net apps would produce purely dll's as you would host those in IIS.

**My question is:**
How do I make `dotnet publish` produce dll's and not exe's when specifying .net461 framework.

**Another way to ask the question is:**
How do I make `dotnet publish` produce a portable app when the frameworks node in project.json looks like this:

```
"frameworks": {
   ".net461": {}
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

so I figured this out... I assumed the standalone application meant that for asp.net core apps you wouldn't normally host them in IIS. That was an incorrect assumption. You still set them up exactly the same way in IIS regarldess of it being a portable application or standalone application. I had other issues which made me think that. I sorted out my other issues by turning on a debugging feature  by using this UseSetting method in Program.cs:

```
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")//TODO: make this config driven to not be deployed in prod. needed for alpha debugging.
                                .Build();

            host.Run();
```

that was equivilant to classic asp.net's "customErrors=off".